# multiple selection shift+click from list

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to implement multiple selection with jquery (jscript) using Shift + click in list:

```
<div class="custom-multi-select-option">
  <span class="custom-multi-select-option-label">Tollet</span>
</div>
<div class="custom-multi-select-option">
  <span class="custom-multi-select-option-label">Present</span>
</div>
```

[List on form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8aic.jpg)

Simple selection implement by adding 
`toggleClass( "custom-multi-select-option-selected" );`
I try this, but it not properly work:

```
var _onClickOnCustomMultiSelect = function( e ){
    $( this ).toggleClass( "custom-multi-select-option-selected" );
    $( this ).find(".custom-multi-select-option-label").toggleClass( "custom-multi-select-option-selected" );
    if(e.shiftKey) {
        $('div.custom-multi-select-option-selected').nextUntil(this).toggleClass( "custom-multi-select-option-selected" );
    }
};
```

Comment: A jsFiddle would be useful.

Comment: It is an implementation of shift+click and ctrl+click http://jsfiddle.net/bMgpc/170/